# If $Y\thicksim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, find $P(Y\text{ is even})$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**The Problem:** Let $Y\thicksim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Calculate the probability $P(Y\text{ is even})$.

**My Attempt:** Recall that the PMF of $Y$ is given by $p_Y(k)=\dfrac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$ for $k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$. Thus we have
$$P(Y\text{ is even})=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^{2n}}{(2n)!}=e^{-\lambda}\left[\frac{e^\lambda+e^{-\lambda}}{2}\right]=\frac{1+e^{-2\lambda}}{2}.$$
Above we used the series expansions of $e^\lambda$ and $e^{-\lambda}$. Mainly,
$$e^\lambda+e^{-\lambda}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-\lambda)^n}{n!}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$

---

Do you agree with my approach above?
Thank you very much for your help and your feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks good!!!!!  Sight check limits for $\lambda \to 0$ = 1 and $\lambda \to \infty$ =1/2.